# An Object Reference is Required fo Access to Non-Static Member

Tags: c#, class, scope, static, object-reference

I apologise, I know this question has been asked a thousand times before by C# beginners (of which I am one), but all the answers I can find say I need to either instantiate the class, or make it static. My class *is* instantiated, and I am trying to access the *instance*. Can anyone take a look at my code and work out what is going wrong?

```
public class RocketSimMain {

    public RocketShip test = new RocketShip ();

    public static void Main() {

        ... // Do some setup stuff here

        //Run the game loop
        while (!EndGameRequested()) {
            test.Move();  <- Object instance error here.
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm instantiating the class and accessing the instance. The only thing that works is instantiating the class inside the Main method, but then I'm not able to access it in other classes.

Comment: `test` is not a static member variable but you're trying to access it from the static `Main()`.

Comment: `test` itself is an instance field, not static. You cannot use it from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `test` static in order to use it from a static method (`Main`).

Answer (score -1):

This problem arises because you are trying to call a **non-static** class from a **static** method.

To solve it you must either make them **both non-static:**

```
public RocketShip test = new RocketShip ();

public void Main() 
    {

    ... // Do some setup stuff here

    //Run the game loop
    while (!EndGameRequested()) 
    {
        test.Move();  <- Object instance error here.
    }
```

or **instantiate it locally within the method:**

```
public static void Main() 
{
     RocketShip test = new RocketShip ();

    ... // Do some setup stuff here

    //Run the game loop
    while (!EndGameRequested()) 
    {
        test.Move();  <- Object instance error here.
    }
}
```